# Checking SVG Upload using Batik

Tags: sax, batik

I try to examine uploaded SVG graphics and look for image elements to read there href attribute. I am using **Batik 1.7** to search for corresponding elements. By using `'getElementsByTagName' / 'getElementsByTagNameNS'` I only get an empty list. Here is my code:

```
try{
    String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
    SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
    SVGDocument doc = f.createSVGDocument(null, upload.getInputStream());
    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

So what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

In fact I was missing nothing, despite the fact that the returned NodeList will be market with length -1 as long as some item is retrieved or the length is queried. So one could say the debugger not always tells the truth.